# How can I show my research when posting a question on how to view which meeting participant admitted a guest from the lobby into an MS Teams meeting?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I posted a question [How can I see which meeting participant admitted a guest from the lobby into the meeting?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/469242/20338), which closed with the following close reason (which is one of the [default close reasons](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3031/20338)):

> Questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

I assume the issue is that my question doesn't show research, since the understanding part is obvious. How should I show my research? I had simply Google the question and didn't find any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask gives a good overview of how to ask questions.

Specifically to your question: As written, we can't know whether you just stumbled across the issue and posted the question, or whether you looked already for an answer on various places without getting any useful answers.

Things which might help to clarify both the problem and show research:

- Is this an issue only on the iPad or on any device?
- What does the documentation of the vendor say about this?
- Is there a product-specific support site where this topic may have been discussed already?